# 7digital Android SDK gives me a NoSuchMethodError for setShouldCache

Tags: java, android, crash, 7digital

I've been trying to update the 7digital SDK in my Android app and I've hit a brick wall. My call to `search` is giving me the following crash:

```
04-09 16:03:42.238    8533-9744/com.myapp.debug E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.myapp.debug, PID: 8533
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setShouldCache(Z)Lcom/android/volley/Request; in class Luk/co/sevendigital/android/sdk/util/VolleyUtil$CacheEntryRequest; or its super classes (declaration of 'uk.co.sevendigital.android.sdk.util.VolleyUtil$CacheEntryRequest' appears in /data/app/com.myapp.debug-1/base.apk)
        at uk.co.sevendigital.android.sdk.util.VolleyUtil$CacheEntryRequest.<init>(VolleyUtil.java:159)
        at uk.co.sevendigital.android.sdk.util.VolleyUtil$StringRequest.<init>(VolleyUtil.java:89)
        at uk.co.sevendigital.android.sdk.util.VolleyUtil.executeStringRequest(VolleyUtil.java:49)
        at uk.co.sevendigital.android.sdk.api.request.track.SDITrackSearchRequest.execute(SDITrackSearchRequest.java:177)
        at uk.co.sevendigital.android.sdk.api.request.track.SDITrackSearchRequest.execute(SDITrackSearchRequest.java:60)
        at uk.co.sevendigital.android.sdk.api.SDIApi$Track.search(SDIApi.java:454)
        at com.myapp.utils.SDSearchTask.doInBackground(SDSearchTask.java:36)
        at com.myapp.utils.SDSearchTask.doInBackground(SDSearchTask.java:20)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The code I'm using to call `search` is:

```
SDIApi myApi = MyApplication.getSDIApi();
SDIApi.Track myTrack = myApi.track();
final SDITrackSearchRequest.Result searchResults = myTrack.search(artist.mName + " " + track.mTrackName);
```

...and the crash and stack trace comes up when I try to step over the `search` line. Does anyone know what might be going on here? I haven't changed my non-library code since using the old version of the library (and there were no errors with that).

Comment: Can you post your gradle dependencies?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem but only when I generate a Signed version of the APK with minifyEnabled true. If I disable the minifyEnabled the app runs without any problem..